# ASP.NET HTTP to HTTPS redirect with www prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect, https

I am using this simple code to redirect http to https on my billing landing page:

```
if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    // send user to SSL 
    string serverName =HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]);        
    string filePath = Request.FilePath;
    Response.Redirect("https://" + serverName + filePath);
}
```

I need it to also check for and add www to the url if it is not already in the url. What do I need to add to this code to accomplish this?

Comment: You should not be encoding the server name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (!serverName.StartsWith("www."))
    serverName = "www." + serverName;
```

Comment: Your example doesn't take case into account. What if the servername was WWW.domain.com, then the result would be www.WWW.domain.com.

Comment: @jessegavin at first glance, I thought that would be the case, but it doesn't duplicate the www.

Comment: @jessegavin: Domain names are normalized to lowercase.  However, you're right; I should have passed `, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Phooey. You're right. Thanks @SLaks. Sorry for accusing you of being wrong @Prismatics.

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes that if the server name doesn't start with a "www." then the remedy is to prepend whatever the current servername is with "www."

```
if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    // send user to SSL 
    string serverName = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
    if (!serverName.ToLowerCaseInvariant().StartsWith("www.")) {
       serverName = string.Format("www.{0}", serverName);
    }
    string filePath = Request.FilePath;
    Response.Redirect("https://" + serverName + filePath);
}
```

Personally, I don't like this method of doing things. I usually create a setting named something like `SecureDomain` and then use logic to verify whether the current ServerName matches that. Something like this.

```
// Suppose the value of GlobalAppSettings.SecureDomain
// is something like www.securestore.com

if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    // send user to SSL 
    string serverName = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
    if (string.Compare(serverName, GlobalAppSettings.SecureDomain, true) != 0) {
       serverName = GlobalAppSettings.SecureDomain;
    }
    string filePath = Request.FilePath;
    Response.Redirect("https://" + serverName + filePath);
}
```

Comment: Hey Jesse, Thanks very much for your assistance. I'm confident that your method would work well, also, but the other response was very simple to just insert inside of what I already had. - Jesse(2)